# How to change Output File FG/BG Color generated from Bash Script (vimdiff)

Tags: bash, shell, vimdiff

I am differentiating two CSV files and generating its output in one html file by using below query:

```
vimdiff Sheet1.csv Sheet2.csv -c TOhtml -c 'w! CsvResult.html' -c 'qa!'
```

In above cmd two csv files (sheet1 and sheet2) in my Windows desktop, and `CsvResult.html` is a file which will show the output of both CSV's in html format.

The HTML file(`CsvResult.html`) which is generating is not visible properly because of different colors,

How to change generated HTML file FG/BG/Text color ? I tried using cmds for text change but it is not applying with file generated.

Comment: Cant you just modify the html directly using sed to add the coloring in the way you need?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios, I have huge files to compare, sed will not work out for changing color of complete html file generated with bash script